# Driver issues with Thinkpad T440/450

Tags: drivers, thinkpad

after using my Lenovo Thinkpad T420, I now plan to upgrade my laptop - possibly to the soon to be available T450.
However, some friends of mine who use a T440 reported several issues regarding drivers and overall functionality using any linux distro.

I did some web search and found multiple threads regarding this topic, all resulting in the advice to wait until better drivers would have been developed.

My question is if there has been an improvement in compatibility and driver availability and if there is any reason to believe that the new Thinkpad will face similar difficulties.

All answers/hints are very much appreciated!